# What does さようなら (左様なら) have to do with "left"?

Tags: kanji, greetings, ateji

What is the relationship between 左様なら and 左? I assume there's some idiomatic meaning for "left" but how does it fit?

Comment: The 左 is ateji, though 様 is not.

Comment: ZhenLin's comment and cypher's answer is right. If it is 上 or 右, then it would mean something proceeding in the context as texts are written from top to bottom or right to left (in ancient times). But for 左, it does not have significant meaning.

Comment: @sawa, I don't understand.  I realize that 左 (as 左記), 右記 and I guess also 上 have the meaning of "the preceding" or "the following" based on the old writing order.  But if it's _ateji_, what difference does it make?

Comment: `以上`, `上記`, `右記` are not ateji.

Comment: Do you mean that 上 and 右 are **never** used as _ateji_?

Comment: @mmdanziger I don't understand why you generalize like that. They are not ateji in the words I mentioned. They may be used in ateji in some other words.

Comment: See also [this post](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/77799/does-%e5%b7%a6%e6%a7%98%e3%81%aa%e3%82%89-say%c5%8dnara-have-chinese-roots/77804#77804) about the full etymology of the word _sayōnara_.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to [this okwave post](http://okwave.jp/qa/q6773033.html), `さよう` was originally written as `然様{さよう}`. It says that `さよう` has the meaning of `そのよう`/`そう` and that the `左` in `左様{さよう}` is an [当{あ}て字{じ}](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ateji) (a Kanji used as a phonetic symbol, rather than for it's meaning.)

In other words, the meaning doesn't have anything to do with `左`, it's uses that character because of it's reading/pronunciation.