# Analysis of kanji for ''sayounara''

Tags: kanji

The kanji for ''sayounara'' is 左様なら

I'm curious about the kanji 左 which means ''left'' as in ''your left hand''.

What is it doing here ?

My understanding is that 左様 means ''this way'' or ''like this'' but why is ''left'' used ?

To me 左様 looks more like ''the left way''.

All thoughts and insights welcome.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/4335/what-does-%e3%81%95%e3%82%88%e3%81%86%e3%81%aa%e3%82%89-%e5%b7%a6%e6%a7%98%e3%81%aa%e3%82%89-have-to-do-with-left It's "ateji", the character 左 is used for its pronunciation, not its meaning.

Comment: はい、ありがとうございました　:)